# Using MYSQL to call a row from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show specific information for my logged in users, i can call the user_name, but i have been able also to call info from the "website" entry which holds the html for the page, i need to be able to call "website" to each logged in user, i.e Susan (user_name) has the html showing when she logs in, BUT Barry (user_name) has the same html showing as susan, as it is being called from Susans row! Please help it is driving me mad!

Here is the code that is on the myaccount.php:

```
Welcome To <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?>'s Account Page</strong>  
<?php   
  if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    echo "<div class=\"error\">$_GET[msg]</div>";
  }
?>
<?php
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());
  $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
  Print "<b></b> ".$info['$website'] . " "; 
?>
```

Comment: im confused, but think you need a where clause in your query, to match the particular person.

Comment: *cough* - `session_start();` - where art thou? - *cough*

Comment: @Fred where does said Code go in the php?

Comment: @BarryMurrell If `session_start();` is not present in any of your file(s), it must be included as the first line underneath your opening PHP tag. I.e.: `<?php session_start(); // rest of your code ?>` and must reside in ALL files used with same session, including any DB connections etc.

Comment: @Fred what does it do? IM brand new to programming, been building and designing for a couple yrs, but only just delved into mysql and proper php

Comment: @BarryMurrell [This on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) will explain it all for you.

Comment: @BarryMurrell You're welcome, enjoy the ride! I too am just getting into MySQLi and PDO. Remember, MySQL and MySQLi are not the same, so don't spend too much time/energy on MySQL, it's been deprecated and not safe to use. Here's a pretty good place to start http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/tag/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `WHERE` clause to your query. If you have a field in your table called user_name it will be like this :

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "'";
```

Note : You are using a deprecated (mysql_query) you should use rather (mysqli_query) which has different syntax 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$_SESSION[user_name]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: That didn't work, i have the user name showing "Welcome To Barry murrells Account Page" with "Welcome To <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?>'s" being the html on myaccount.php However this code: `Welcome To <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?>'s Account Page</strong>  
   <?php 
      if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
   echo "<div class=\"error\">$_GET[msg]</div>";
   }
   ?>
     <?php
       $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") 
 or die(mysql_error());
 $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
 Print "<b></b> ".$info['website'] . " "; 
 ?> `

Comment: ** Calls the column "website" on the first row of the table called who is my "first user" the website column for this user contains the html for that page - i can't make it appear on the page any way else! - I am aware that i need a WHERE but the code you gave me has now stopped the html showing at all :(**

Comment: Ive sorted it, i used the username coloumn and changed the type to text from tiny text and will just post the html into that, i did get a syntax error and a website not known on db, but that was all

Comment: I also deleted the first entry as it was set to primary, it all works a treat now [http://ableair.co.uk/register.php]